# Xcode - SwiftyStoreKit invalid product id

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, provisioning

I hope you can help me.

I followed a tutorial on youtube for in app purchasing in Xcode. Therefore I'm using SwiftyStoreKit.

Unfortunately I get the error invalid productid.

I followed this page: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/
Unfortunately I couldn't solve it.

1) InApp-Purchasing is enabled in my App

2) Cleared for sale for my in-app purchasing
[image]

3) Bundle ID matches the App ID

4) I've generated new provisioning profile and configured it in Xcode.
[image]
[image]

5) Reinstalled the app

6) Cleaned project and rebuilt it.

7) the correct productid is passed to the purchase method.
[image]

8) credit card or financial information are submitted in the account

Is there something else I've forgotten?

Please help!

Thanks in advance.